# Confusion on closure definition in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $(X,\tau)$

> A point $x$ is said to be in the closure of $A$ if, for
> each neighborhood $N$ of $x$, $N\cap A\neq\emptyset$

(Mandelson's Introduction to topology)

Suppose that $x\notin X$, then there is no neighboorhood $N$ of $x$, since there is no open set $O\in\tau$ containing $x$. Therefore the condition for $x$ to be in the closure of A is satisfied. (''$N$ is a neighborhood of $x$'' $\rightarrow$ ''$N\cap A\neq\emptyset$'' is true,  since ''$N$ is a neighborhood of $x$'' is always false )

Thus any element that is not in $X$ is in the closure of any subset of X.

How do we prevent this from being true ? I suppose specyfying that $x$ is in $X$ would work, but is it necessary ?

Thank you

Comment: When working with a topological space $X$ it makes no sense to say anything about points *not* in $X.$ In that sense $X$ is similar to the "universe of discourse" used in basic set theory.

Comment: youpi, thank you !

Comment: Adding to @coffeemath 's explanation, for definitions that are only meant to be defined within a certain `universe'  or set, it is common to add qualifiers to the definition to make the point clear. For example, your definition can be easily fixed by saying "A point $x \in X$ is said to be in the closure of $A \subseteq X$ if, for each neighbourhood $N$ of $x$, $N\cap A\neq\emptyset$ ". It is understandable why the author didn't add these qualifiers, as they are often taken to be implicit for the reason coffemath says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we're working in a space $(X,\tau)$ it makes no sense to talk about points not in $X$, when talking about topological questions, like whether a point is in the closure of some set or not. In this context we can *only* talk about points in the closure of sets $A \subseteq X$ and that closure $\overline{A}$ is then a subset of $X$ too. Points outside do not "count".

When we give $A \subseteq X$ the subspace topology (wrt $X$) and $B \subseteq A$ we can talk about *two* closures: that of $B$ wrt $(X, \tau)$ and that of $B$ wrt $A$ (in its own subspace) topology and in that case we have the theorem $$\overline{B}^{(A)} = \overline{B}^{(X)} \cap A$$ which is quite straightforward to see from the definition of the subspace topology.

E.g. if we have $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology and $A=\Bbb Q$ in the subspace topology, then $B =\{q \in \Bbb Q\mid q^2 < 2\}$ is its own closure in $\Bbb Q$ but has closure $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$ in $\Bbb R$. So context matters when talking about closures, but we cannot go outside the ''universe'' $\Bbb R$ (here). So it makes no sense to ask whether $i \in \overline{A}$.